# How to update database based on variable api result?

Tags: php, mysql, logic

I would like to get your help to get the best and cleanest way to update my video database (MySQL).

Those videos are ordered into folders and I can only grab those folders one by one.

My server in using an external api to grab thousands of videos (each video including an unique id, folder id, title, url...).

As I want to make as less api call as possible, I would like to run a daily cron job to browse each folder and add the new videos, and remove the removed video.

At the moment I can browse all the folders, looping trough each video and adding it to the database.

```
while (true){
$videos = video_get($oid, $offset, $count);
$videos = $videos['response']['items'];

$results = count($videos);
echo $results . ' || ' . $offset;

if ($results > 0){
    $offset += $results;

    foreach ($videos as $video) {
        $i++;
        echo "<br>Number : " . $i;
        echo "<br>";
        $data = Array (
            "id" => $video['id'],
            "folder_id" => $video['folder_id'],
            "title" => $video['title'],
            "url" => $video['url']
        );
        $db->insert('videos', $data);
    }
}
else {break;}
}
```

What I am asking is, cosidering that there are about 100000 videos, aranged into around 20 folders, would it be better to add all the video and remove the duplicate, or check if the video exist and then add it into the db in case it is a new one?

And more important, what would be the best way to remove the video that wont be present anymore in the api request?

I hope I have been clear enough, but just in  case:

Videos are ordered by folder.

Videos can be added/removed at any time on the api side.

I want to keep all the videos into my database, and update them based of if they have been new/removed videos on the api side, in order to avoid having to call the api too often.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Porn videos? You naughty person!

Comment: What type of DB? MySQL?

Comment: I missed that important point in fact, yes the database is MySQL.

As for the first comment, I just forgot to "edit" this part of my code :p